# Updating style.css

Tags: css, wordpress

I updated my style.css sheet to get rid of a white space at the top of my pages. I know exactly what line of code to edit because when I inspect the page and make changes I can get rid of the white bar. However, when I change this in the style sheet nothing happens. It saves my changes on the style sheet but when I go back to the inspector on the page it hasn't been changed. Is there something I need to do to make sure this change effects the right pages?

This is the section I have changed:

```
.page_content_wrap 
{
padding: 0;
}
```

This is how it appears on the inspector:

```
.page_content_wrap 
{
padding: 5em 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: we cant help if you don't provide code

Comment: I understand how to ask a question. I just didnt think the code would help with the problem solving on this one. Nevertheless I have updated the post with the section of code that I am editing. Please tell me if that helps you answer the question.

Comment: When you inspect it, it should tell you where it's getting the value from. It's probably because you have it specified with the `5em` elsewhere, in some place that takes precedence over your style sheet file. So no, it doesn't really help anyone answer the question, but it's a start. Tell everyone where the second bit of code comes from.

Comment: have you tried private browsing to inspect this property?

Comment: Thanks BobRodes. This was the problem. It was being inherited for another .div section. I changed the right settings and it everything looks great now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well,you didn't mention about what Html/Css framework you are using. I think your css is getting overrided.Try with this

```
.page_content_wrap 
 {
  padding: 0 !important;
 }
```